# Autofac - Components ignore dependency defined in lifetime scope

Tags: c#, autofac, lifetime-scoping

I could well be misunderstanding something here, so perhaps there is a simple answer here but I'm currently scratching my head.

I have a class UnitOfWork that implements IUnitOfWork (yes yes I know). The constructor for unit of work takes an IPrincipalFactory. TResponder is the top level of the graph which takes an IUnitOfWork.

I'm trying to register the ApplicationPrincipalFactory as a specific instance in a lifetime scope... it's dependant on some properties passed to the HandleAsync function. I'm doing the following:

```
    public async Task<TResponse> HandleAsync<TMessage, TResponse, TResponder>(TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class
        where TResponder : IRespondAsync<TMessage, TResponse>
    {
        using (var scope = this.BeginLifetimeScope(message))
        {
            var responder = scope.Resolve<TResponder>();
            return await responder.Respond(message);
        }
    }

    private ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope<TMessage>(TMessage message)
    {
        var unwrapped = GetDomainContext(message);
        var applicationPrincipalFactory = this.CreateApplicationPrincipalFactory(unwrapped);

        var lifetime = this.container.BeginLifetimeScope(
            r => r.RegisterInstance(applicationPrincipalFactory).As<IPrincipalFactory>());

        return lifetime;
    }

    private ApplicationPrincipalFactory CreateApplicationPrincipalFactory(IDomainContext unwrapped)
    {
        var applicationPrincipalFactory =
            new ApplicationPrincipalFactory(
                unwrapped.Tenant,
                unwrapped.ActingTenant,
                unwrapped.Username);

        return applicationPrincipalFactory;
    }
```

Based on everything I've read, defining the dependency within BeginLifetimeScope(r => should override the parent container binding, so when I call resolve, it should all slot neatly together.

However, I get an exception:

```
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Platform.Engine.Persistence.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Platform.Engine.Security.IPrincipalFactory principalFactory' of constructor
```

I am not registering the IPrincipalFactory anywhere other than in this method. The IUnitOfWork is defined in the outer scope as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I have also tried re-defining the unitofwork registration within the child container in case it was an issue cause by registering it in the outer container rather than the lifetime one:

```
        var lifetime = this.container.BeginLifetimeScope(
            r => r.RegisterInstance(applicationPrincipalFactory).As<IPrincipalFactory>());

        var overrides = new ContainerBuilder();
        overrides.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
        overrides.Update(lifetime.ComponentRegistry);

        return lifetime;
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing... any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a `builder.RegisterType` line for your `IPrincipalFactory`?

Comment: I do not... would the RegisterInstance(...).As<IPrincipalFactory> not be acting in it's place here?

Comment: Not really sure, I've not used Autofac like that, but based on the error message I'm guessing not. I usually just register each of my types using the builder and let Autofac handle the rest.

Comment: Could you post a repro please. Take the following gist as a base: https://gist.github.com/alexandrnikitin/9799e871bbcd573fc20b

Comment: Which scope (container or lifetime scope) do you resolve `IUnitOfWork` from?

Answer (score 0):

Register your factory with the rest of your types during the initial container configuration.

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationPrincipalFactory>().As<IPrincipalFactory>();
```

Then in your lifetime scope resolve a delegate factory that you can pass the context into.

```
var factory = container.Resolve<Func<IDomainContext, IPrincipalFactory>>();
var instance = factory(context);
```

You could also add three `string` parameters to the `Func<>` signature, but since you already have a nice context object I would just pass that in instead.

Finally, use the factory as needed.

```
instance.DoesSomethingButNotSureWhat();
```

That will prevent you from having to update the lifetime scope just to pass in the context parameter.